# CFBundleExecutable missing or invalid

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode6.3

Attempting to run my project in the iOS simulator, I get a launch code error '0'.  Checking the console logs in CoreSimulator.log I found the .app executable **"has missing or invalid CFBundleExecutable in its Info.plist"**.  I'm not sure how to deal with this issue.  Perhaps making sure the CFBundleExecutable file is named correctly, but what exactly is it supposed to be named?

Comment: Show us the complete app bundle and the contents of the `Info.plist` file.

Comment: reset your simulator and run again